# ANTLR Ambiguity Issue

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr

I have this grammar.

```
grammar MyGrammar;
prog : lexeme* ;

lexeme :
TOK_INTLIT  : [0-9]+;
Identifiers  : Letter (Letter | Digit | '_' )* ;
fragment Letter     : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment Digit      : [0-9] ;
...
```

Now when I input this: `int 2x = 20;`

I am expecting an error for identifier but I am getting an output like this:

```
Type = TOK_INT value = [int] Line 1, Column 0,
Type = TOK_INTLIT value = [2] Line 1, Column 4,
Type = Identifiers value = [x] Line 1, Column 5,
```

`2x` is being split. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to fix such things?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Won't that sequence of tokens be rejected by the grammar anyway? Or would `int 2 x = 20;` actually be legal? In the latter case, why shouldn't `int 2x = 20;` also be legal?

Comment: Why are you surprised that `2x` is being tokenized as `TOK_INTLIT` followed by an `Identifiers` token?

Comment: well, I want to show an error on 2x because an identifier can only begin with a letter.Should I get put a grammar for an error token so that it recognizes the wrong sequence?

Comment: @MissakBoyajian Yes, an identifier can only start with a letter, but a number can (and must) start with a digit. It's not like the tokenizer is telling you that "2x" is an identifier. It's telling you that "2" is a number and "x" is an identifier, which is in accordance with the rules. If you have a grammar rule `typedecl : type Identifiers '=' expression ';'`, then ANTLR will correctly complain that `int 2x = 20;` is invalid because you supplied a number where an identifier was expected. Is that not what you want?