# How to create a lexical analyzer in ANTLR 4 that can catch different types of lexical errors

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I am using ANTLR 4 to create my lexer, but I don't how to create a lexical analyzer that catches different types of lexical errors.

For example:

1. If I have an unrecognized symbol like `^` the lexical analyzer should a report an error like this "Unrecognized symbol "^" "
2. If I have an invalid identifier like `2n` the lexical analyzer should report an error like this "identifier "2n" must begin with a letter"

Please can you help me.

Comment: The ANTLR documentation talks about handling errors.
Could you provide sample code for your parse tree listener, the grammar you're working on, and some sample inputs?

Comment: How should the lexer know that `2n` is even supposed to be an identifier?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661601/antlr-ambiguity-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an error token rule for each known error and an "catchall" error token rule at the end like this:

```
// valid tokens first!
Number : [0-9]+;
Identifier : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
//...

// "error" tokens
// don't use these tokens in your grammar; They will show up as extraneous tokens during parsing and can be handled if desired.
InvalidIdentifier : [0-9]([0-9a-zA-Z])+; 
ACommonInvalidToken : '^'; // if you want to be more specific for certain cases
// add more to address common mistakes

UnknownToken : . ; // the "catch-all" error token; be sure not to be too greedy...
```