# defining rule for identifiers in ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, flex-lexer

I'm trying to write a grammar in ANTLR, and the rules for recognizing IDs and int literals are written as follows:

```
ID : Letter(Letter|Digit|'_')*;
TOK_INTLIT : [0-9]+ ;
//this is not the complete grammar btw
```

and when the input is :

```
void main(){
    int 2a;
}
```

the problem is, the lexer is recognizing **2** as an int literal and **a** as an ID, which is completely logical based on the grammar I've written, but I don't want 2a to be recognized this way, instead I want an error to be displayed since identifiers cannot begin with something other than a letter... I'm really new to this compiler course... what should be done here?

Comment: Why do people [keep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661601/antlr-ambiguity-issue) [wanting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678232/how-to-create-a-lexical-analyzer-in-antlr-4-that-can-catch-diiferent-types-of-le) this? What's the problem with getting an "unexpected int" error in the parser?

Comment: @sepp2k: Maybe the instructor is trying to make a point. Perhaps her students should get together and discuss the problem *with each other* instead of asking us.

Answer (score 1):

It's at least interesting that in C and C++, `2n` is an invalid number, not an invalid identifier. That's because the C lexer (or, to be more precise, the preprocessor) is *required* by the standard to interpret any sequence of digits and letters starting with a digit as a "preprocessor number". Later on, an attempt is made to reinterpret the preprocessor number (if it is still part of the preprocessed code) as one of the many possible numeric syntaxes. `2n` isn't, so an error will be generated at that point.

Preprocessor numbers are more complicated than that, but that should be enough of a hint for you to come up with a simple solution for your problem.

Comment: Bonus question: what is the difference between `0x7f+1` and `0x7e+2`?

Comment: The second is probably recognized as float.